# JSLink and lookup field problem

Tags: lookup-column, custom-field-types, jslink, client-side-rendering

I am trying to make a cross site lookup field. So for now I made javaScript file and overrided the JSLink parameter.

I want to made it clear for sharepoint and followed `clientforms.debug.js` practice.

In `clientforms.debug.js` they used `updateControlValue` method for update fieldValue.

So, I use this method for insert my own lookup object to field value. And main problem - updating field value such as the string  `5233;#HelpMePlz`.

Because after method `updateControlValue`, SharePoint does not save my own `object.LookupValue (HelpMePlz)`,

SharePoint only save `object.LookupId (5233)`.

I need someone who has already done something similar and can explain the subtleties of working with a client side rendering (JSLink) & lookup field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested - it was necessary to set up the field, then values ​​began to persist.

**UPDATE:**
That was i mean. This is cut of `public partial class LookupFieldProperties : UserControl, IFieldEditor`.

```
     public void OnSaveChange(SPField field, bool isNewField)
     {
        var lookUpField = (LookupField)field;

        if (lookUpField == null)
            return;

        lookUpField.WebProperty = WebPropertyEditor.Text;
        lookUpField.LookupViewId = ViewPropertyEditor.Text;

        if (lookUpField.LookupList != null)
            return;

        using (var web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb(WebPropertyEditor.Text, true))
        {
            var listId = web.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl,
                "/Lists/" + ListPropertyEditor.Text)).ID;
            lookUpField.LookupWebId = web.ID;
            lookUpField.LookupList = listId.ToString();
        }

        lookUpField.AllowMultipleValues = AllowMultipleValuesEditor.Checked;
        lookUpField.LookupField = FieldPropertyEditor.Text;
    }
```

Comment: When you say "setup" what do you mean more precisely?

Comment: @RobertLindgren i update my answer.